# How to Self learn math

Tags: soft-question

Can someone suggest a website that will guide me and also teach the branches of mathematics??

Comment: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/)

Comment: @FredKline does it give a sequence??

Comment: They cover a lot of math. Browse the contents to find something that suits you.

Comment: Wow, you think MIT OCW will not be enough?!

Comment: @BharathGRon [This site](http://hbpms.blogspot.com.br) contains a order. Also, look [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/394655/25805). I'd advise you to start with Lang's [Basic Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Basic-Mathematics-Serge-Lang/dp/0387967877) and [Geometry](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-A-High-School-Course/dp/0387966544) if you're in a really basic level. Good luck.

Comment: @ireallydonknow He's probably missing the order in which the subjects must be studied.

Comment: @BharathGRon What particular subjects in mathematics do you need to/would you like to learn?

Comment: @ireallydonknow i meant it wont guid you in a direction

Comment: @PristineKavalostka you got the point

Comment: @BharathGRon Get the books I mentioned and see if you know stuff from them.

Comment: @BharathGRon Your question is probably appropriate for the nearly-in-beta-SE http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64216/mathematics-learning-studying-and-education. 

Check out the proposal and commit to it if you're interested. Then we can get it off the ground and get the site in beta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I would say there are many different ways for learning math. Web resources are very useful but can only guide you according to their program, which may or may not be what you want.

Just in case you are really looking forward to learn math seriously, you could use the following guidelines that are based on what my teachers said and stuff I've read on the web.

Please note that I'm assuming you don't know much about math and would like to learn everything.

-You could begin studying logic, there are many good books for that, and if my memory doesn't fail, [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/intrologic) offered a course on logic which it probably will run again anytime soon. You could also check [this one](https://www.coursera.org/course/maththink) out

-Other big branch of math is set theory. If you went through school, you probably saw it every year. It turns out it's a very important branch of math which you should never forget. You could study this (as well as every other branch of math) from books (I can't give you any hints on which books since I haven't used any books for learning set theory). [This](https://www.coursera.org/course/mathphil) course seems to have some set theory but also many other topics. Since it's supposed to be self-contained, you could just as well take it the next time it's open.

-You could then learn Calculus. There are many good books for learning this subject but you could use either Coursera, MIT OCW, or Khan academy as you have been told.

-Now, there are many other things you could learn if you want to go really deep in math. Some may note that I've listed Calculus before Algebra. This may seem unforgivable but that's just the way I learnt it (I didn't have that much of a good base). Algebra is a really huge branch of math, I think online resources can give you only the basics (surely there are some high-level algebra courses at MIT but I don't know if their materials are all in the OCW). Books will be your best friends for more and more advanced math.

-The same applies to topology and to pretty much every other big branch of math. I'm not continuing this listing since I don't know topology nor other branches of math. By the time you're going deeper into algebra, you will probably already know what comes next and what is the best way for you to tackle it.

Hope I helped.